# Haskell FFI memory allocation performance issue

Tags: c++, performance, haskell, ffi

I'm using an FFI to C to send medium-large amounts of data (~100MB) to a C program -- just a list of strings. However, all of the methods I've used seem to take unreasonable amounts of time (~10 sec). Upon profiling, it appears to be the actual memory allocation that takes time. I've tried:

- sending as regular strings (`newCString`)
- conversion to ByteStrings (`unsafeUseAsCString`)
- conversion to vector of chars (`unsafeWith >>= withForeignPtr ...`)

What is the fastest way to send data across a C FFI?

Comment: How long are those strings? How many of them? Aren't you able to provide a small example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: How is your data represented to start with?

Comment: It's a standard type with 5 fields, and I'm converting to/from strings to pass to a database client in C. I've additionally tried allocating all at once with mallocBytes and there seems to be just as slow. Another datapoint is that GHC's profiling indicated that ~15 GBs were being allocated for this ~100MB set of data.

Comment: Also tried standard marshalling with newCString (above) and using Data.Vector.Storable to store a list of Storable chars.

Comment: Well it's hard to give advice about what you should do without any code, but one thing you definitely shouldn't do is process 100MB worth of `String`s, which will already account for at least 4GB of heap allocation.

Answer (score 0):

As Reid Barton said in comments, if you have 100MB of strings, your allocation will be terrible to begin with, no matter what you do with it.

Your slowdown isn't from the FFI, its from having 100MB of strings to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to make a custom data type, using a [`MutableByteArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6.2.0/docs/Data-Primitive-ByteArray.html#t:MutableByteArray) allocated with [`newAlignedPinnedByteArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6.2.0/docs/Data-Primitive-ByteArray.html#v:newAlignedPinnedByteArray), and turned into something that can be passed to C with [`mutableByteArrayContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6.2.0/docs/Data-Primitive-ByteArray.html#v:mutableByteArrayContents).

The alternative, if you can rewrite the C API you're interfacing with, is to give the C function a `FunPtr` which passes it a reasonable-sized chunk of the Haskell data you're working with at a time.